# Alternatives to <?= ... ?> syntax in php

Tags: php

Is there any alternative for directly inserting the value of a php variable into html or javascript other than `<?= ... ?>` which my joyent hosting server doesn't seem to support . I know I could use echo but that would end up looking clumsy .

Comment: It's not clumsy, I don't see how "portable" is clumsy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `short_open_tag` is disabled by your provider you'll have to use `<? echo`. See the [php.ini documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you can use Heredoc, which allows you to embed variables using the `{$...}` syntax:

```
<?php

$var = 5;

print <<<__END_OF_BLOCK__
The value of var is: {$var}
__END_OF_BLOCK__;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, `<?php echo $string ?>` is the long version. However, if you have access to the php.ini file, you can turn the `<?=` on - it's `short_open_tag`. One thing though - if you want your code to be as portable as possible, use the long tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use
    `<?php echo("some thing"); ?>`
instead. They will not prevent the use of echo function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that would look smth like :

```
function _e($str)
{
   echo $str;
}
```

add this function somewhere where it will be accessible in the whole app then use it like this :

```
<?php _e('hello world');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php ... ?>` instead. That's standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing this up at the start of your script.

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', 1);
```

Although, as others have mentioned, you should probably just use `<?php echo $foo; ?>` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

Use a template engine!

It's always a good idea to separate code from logic. I like [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/).

Then , instead of

```
Hello, <?php echo $user_name ?>!
```

you will write

```
Hello, {{ user_name }}!
```

The template engine will take some of your time to learn it, but trust me, it's always worth it.